# Reverse foreign key relation in Django ORM

Tags: python, django

How to return all objects  instances of a particular model  that are being addresed as Foreign key by ANY object instance of a different model ?  Lets say there is a model Item  and a model ItemRequested that has foreign key relation to Item. How to print all Items that are being mentioned as foreign key in the ItemRequested table/model ? basically this is the SQL query that i want to execute in Django:

```
select * from backend_item where id in (select id from backend_itemrequested);
```

Obviously i want to avoid executing raw SQL commands from inside Django ORM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking here. But perhaps this is what you want:

```
Item.objects.exclude(itemrequested=None)
```

Comment: I really tried to be as clear as possible but your  anwser actually  was on spot sir!

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you, as a sign to future searchers.